# Notification gcm

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
 private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification(extras.getString("Notice"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Notification.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            //0, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
   // .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("MobileHealth")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Here is my code for notification. i am able to get the message using the ip address when i have first send the message but now when i am using a new ip address i am not able to get the message and in the log cat it displays Invalid app and invalid package name : perhaps you didnot include a pendingIntent in the extras

Comment: check if remote mysql is connected properly on server or chk srvices logs

Comment: create browser key instead of server key. and just create it without inserting anything and use that key in your project.